# Xamarin loads new screen before facebook login is done

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin

I am working on a facebook login to an app. But when I add the code that should direct it to the homescreen after the facebook login, it just go straight to the homescreen, bypassing the facebook login. Without the code the facebook login works fine.

I have the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Xamarin.Auth;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GMaps
{
    [Activity (Label = "PrivateParty", MainLauncher = true, Theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar",Icon = "@drawable/Icon")]           
    public class LoginActivity : Activity
    {
        RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
        Button mButton;
        Button fbButton;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.LoginView);

            mButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonSkip);
            fbButton = FindViewById<Button>     (Resource.Id.buttonSignInFacebook);

        mButton.Click += mButton_Click;
        fbButton.Click += delegate { facebookLogin();};

    }

    void mButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this , typeof(MainActivity));
        this.StartActivity (intent);
        this.Finish (); //Prevents return to loginscreen
    }

    void facebookLogin()
    {
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId: "***************",
            scope: "",
            authorizeUrl: new Uri("http://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")
        );

        auth.AllowCancel = true;

        auth.Completed += (s, ee) => {
            if(!ee.IsAuthenticated){
                //Not Authenticated
                var error = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                error.SetMessage("Not Authenticated");
                error.SetPositiveButton("Go back", (o, eee) => {});
                error.Create().Show();
                return;
            }

            //make request for data (method, url, parameters, account)
            var getUserData = new OAuth2Request ("GET", new Uri("http://graph.facebook.com/me"), null, ee.Account);
            getUserData.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith( t => {
                var test = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
                string awesomenessOfDoom = null;
                var profileInfo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t.Result.GetResponseText());
                //var profileInfo = JObject.Parse(t.Result.GetResponseText());
//To test the data we get from FB
                /*foreach(var item in profileInfo){
                    awesomenessOfDoom = awesomenessOfDoom + item.ToString() + " | ";
                }
                test.SetMessage(awesomenessOfDoom);
                test.SetPositiveButton ("Ok", (o, e) => { });
                test.Create().Show();*/
            }, UIScheduler);

        };

        var intent = auth.GetUI (this);
        StartActivity (intent);



        //The code I am running but doesn't work
        var intentDone = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
        this.StartActivity (intentDone);
        this.Finish ();
    }
    private static readonly TaskScheduler UIScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();  
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StartActivity` is asynchronous so execution continues immediately without waiting for the authentication. This is why it just goes straight to the home screen.

Move this code into the `auth.Completed` handler:

`var intentDone = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
this.StartActivity (intentDone);`